# After TRUNCATE TABLE, how can I recover the data?

Tags: oracle

I need to recover data truncated in Oracle table.

There are any folder in Linux where stores the truncated data?
Is there any table which store the information of table after truncating?

I am not DBA.

Comment: Restore your backup

Comment: How it could be do? I need to have activated the FlashBack? I readed something about RMAN, but there were some other changes after truncating table. And I just need to restore the table.

Comment: Unless you created a restore point **in advance**, you have to restore database from backup.

Comment: Give me some commands to check if I can restore please. I am not DBA,

Answer (score 4):

If you have not backed up the table (for example, by using `RMAN`, `EXPDP` or `EXP`) or [created a `RESTORE POINT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/using-flasback-database-restore-points.html#GUID-909BBEEF-389B-443B-8CD7-F3C027AAFFF3) then your data is lost.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707):

> **Caution:**
>
> You cannot roll back a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement, nor can you use a `FLASHBACK TABLE` statement to retrieve the contents of a table that has been truncated.

You can check if you have an `RMAN` backup by logging into `RMAN` (rather than into the database) and using the [`LIST` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/LIST.html#GUID-2BAB704C-A3C9-4F76-8D96-4BD961FBEF2E).

You can [check if you have a restore point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/using-flasback-database-restore-points.html#GUID-1A583D44-66CB-4D21-B170-2A07CFF6EE65) (from a database user with the appropriate permissions) using:

```sql
SELECT name,
       guarantee_flashback_database,
       pdb_restore_point,
       clean_pdb_restore_point,
       pdb_incarnation#,
       storage_size
FROM   v$restore_point;
```

You are looking for a restore point where `guarantee_flashback_database` is `YES`.

*(Assuming that the `RESTORE POINT` was created after the table was created and populated.)*

**Note:**

- If you restore from a backup or to a restore point then all changes made since that backup or creating the restore point will be lost.

---

To answer your additional questions:

> [Are] there are any folder in Linux where stores the truncated data?

No

> Is there any table which store the information of table after truncating?

No

Comment: Have you any command to check if FLASHBACK is enable? I cannot access to V$DATABASE table.
It must be DBA who has to recover?

Comment: @VahramDanielyan If you have not created a backup then your data is **LOST** and cannot be recovered. Asking a DBA will not help you unless they are going to tell you that there is a backup that they can restore from. Flashback will not help.

Comment: Tell me please how can I check with DBA account The RMAN data into specific table. I have the DBA account, and we was made some changes in other packages. Just I want to recover data to specific table.

Comment: @VahramDanielyan Updated, log into `RMAN` and use the `LIST` command.